# How to optimise this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is part of a large weather widget for iPhone.
Although the code below works fine I would like to know how can I optimise this so I don't have the fail function twice?
Thanks.

```
function updateWeather() {
var files = "widgetweather" + xmlnumber + ".xml";
if (typeof groovyAPI !== 'undefined') { 
    groovyAPI.do ({ read: files }, function(data) { weatherHandler(data);
    }).fail( function () {
        document.getElementById("Day0desc").innerHTML = "No widgetweather.xml file !";
        document.getElementById("WeatherInfoBG").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("forecastBG").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("hourlyforecastBG").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("mooninfoBG").style.display = "none"; 
    });
} else { 
    if (XML_TEST == true) { url = files; } else { url = "file:///private/var/mobile/Documents/" + files; }
        jQuery.get(url, function(data) { weatherHandler(data);
        }).fail( function () {
        document.getElementById("Day0desc").innerHTML = "No widgetweather.xml file !";
        document.getElementById("WeatherInfoBG").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("forecastBG").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("hourlyforecastBG").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("mooninfoBG").style.display = "none"; 
    }); 
} 
// REINITIALIZE THE TIMER TO NOT LAUNCH MULTIPLE INSTANCES OF THE FUNCTION  
clearTimeout(refreshTimer); 
refreshTimer = setTimeout(updateWeather, 30*1000);
}
```

Comment: This question is better suited on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: `.fail(myFailFunction);` ... It looks like you know how to use referenced function, so your question doesn't make  much sense

Comment: You may want to move "document.getElementById"-lines into a function.

Comment: Also, is there any reason to use native JS when you have jQuery and it's selector API available? I.e. `document.getElementById("Day0desc").innerHTML = "No widgetweather.xml file !";` can be changed to `$('#Day0desc').html('No widgetweather.xml file !');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function updateWeather() {
var files = "widgetweather" + xmlnumber + ".xml";
if (typeof groovyAPI !== 'undefined') { 
    groovyAPI.do ({ read: files }, function(data) { weatherHandler(data);
    }).fail(noWidget);
} else { 
    if (XML_TEST == true) { url = files; } else { url = "file:///private/var/mobile/Documents/" + files; }
        jQuery.get(url, function(data) { weatherHandler(data);
        }).fail(noWidget);
} 
// REINITIALIZE THE TIMER TO NOT LAUNCH MULTIPLE INSTANCES OF THE FUNCTION  
clearTimeout(refreshTimer); 
refreshTimer = setTimeout(updateWeather, 30*1000);
}

function noWidget(){
        document.getElementById("Day0desc").innerHTML = "No widgetweather.xml file !";
        document.getElementById("WeatherInfoBG").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("forecastBG").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("hourlyforecastBG").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("mooninfoBG").style.display = "none"; 
}
```

Comment: It works after I remove the brace, bracket & semi-colon after the second }).fail(noWidget); Thanks.

Comment: Ofcourse, mybad. whent a litle fast copying and editing your code! Good that it worked!